# Why do we use probability to calculate precision recall curve instead of actual class?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, precision-recall

If I'm not wrong, We calculate precision and recall values for classifiers by final label predicted. However, the`precision_recall_curve` in `sklearn` uses `decision_function` instead of final class labels. Does it have any special impact on the final values? Does the extent of confidence impact the curve in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The precision-recall curve is defined by varying the decision threshold.  For each threshold, you get a different hard classifier whose precision and recall you can compute, and so you get a point on the curve.

> The `precision_recall_curve` computes a precision-recall curve from the ground truth label and a score given by the classifier by varying a decision threshold.

[Precision, recall and F-measures | Scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#precision-recall-f-measure-metrics)

If you pass `y_pred` as the class predictions, then the precision recall curve becomes degenerate, having only have three points: `(0,1)`, `(1,0)`, and the point corresponding to your (hard) classifier's precision and recall.

Answer (score 2):

[`precision_recall_curve`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve.html) from sklearn doesn't use any additional decision function to calculate the scores. It uses the `true` and `predicted` values to calculate the precision and recall values. Here's an example:

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve
y_true = [1,1,0,1,1]
y_pred = [0.5, 0.9, 0.1, 0.9, 0.9]

precision, recall, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(y_true, y_pred)
```

Comment: Yeah that worked too, but in the documentation they have said `probas_pred` instead of y_pred, and i found a slight performance difference.

Comment: yes, I saw that too. `probas_pred` requires an `array` input, we can't pass a function directly.